# bit_pattern_31_[256*4] in opencv orb feature detector

Tags: opencv, feature-detection, orb, slam

I'm learning orb-slam and  opencv source code, and inside the `orb.cpp`  which lies on modules/features2d/src/ directory I see a bit pattern named as

```
bit_pattern_31_[256*4]
```

But I really don't know what's its usage. I search the google and bing long time without any answer given.
So any one know the usage or reference of this majic bit pattern?

Comment: did you get any explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Since I came across this on google and eventually found what I think is the answer, I'll give it a shot:

```
bit_pattern_31_[]
```

is a pre-computed set of points P1(x,y) and P2(x,y).

I believe it to be the set of points obtained by the greedy search described in section *4.3 Learning Good Binary Features* of the original orb paper (ORB: an efficient alternative to SIFT or SURF)